# how to consume data in rest api that returns xml data in android

Tags: android, api, rest

please can anybody tell how to consume rest **API** in android that returns `xml` data.there are so many example with `JSON`.but I need to response in `xml` format ...can anybody tell how to do that please help me thanks in advance.

Comment: have to tried `Volley`

Comment: whts is this? i m a beginner

Comment: It's library for network communication

Comment: i m passing string school id to return data as school name.but its showing exception occured,this is my code

Comment: where is your code ?

Comment: is it correct ????????

Comment: Android having some predefined api for xml parsing.you can use that.Otherwise you can use kxml api (Third party api).

Comment: okie...how to do that

Comment: its showing "exception occured"  :(

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this

```
private class CallAPI extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {



    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
      String urlString=params[0]; // URL to call
      String schid="";
      String resultToDisplay = "";
      InputStream in = null;
      Result result = null ;


      // HTTP Get
      try {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
        //resultToDisplay +="&" + URLEncoder.encode("data", "UTF-8") ; 
      } catch (Exception e ) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        return e.getMessage();
      }

       // Parse XML
       XmlPullParserFactory pullParserFactory;
       try {
            pullParserFactory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            XmlPullParser parser = pullParserFactory.newPullParser();
            parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false); 
            parser.setInput(in, null);
            result = parseXML(parser);
       } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }

       // Simple logic to determine if the email is dangerous, invalid, or valid
       if (result != null ) {
         if( result.hygieneResult.equals("Spam Trap")) {
           resultToDisplay = "Dangerous, please correct";
         }
         else if( Integer.parseInt(result.statusNbr) >= 300) {
           resultToDisplay = "Invalid, please re-enter";
         }
         else {
           resultToDisplay = "Thank you for your submission";
         }

       }
       else {
         resultToDisplay = "Exception Occured";
       }

       return resultToDisplay;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String schid) {
        if(schid == null) {
            schid = "THERE WAS AN ERROR";
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ResultActivity.class); 
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, schid);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private Result parseXML( XmlPullParser parser ) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
      int eventType = parser.getEventType();
      Result result = new Result(); 

      while( eventType!= XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
      String strid = null;
      switch(eventType)
      {
        case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
            strid = parser.toString();
            //name=parser.getName();
          if( strid.equals("Error")) {
            System.out.println("Web API Error!");
          }
          else if ( strid.equals("StatusNbr")) {
            result.statusNbr = parser.nextText();
          }
          else if (strid.equals("HygieneResult")) {
            result.hygieneResult = parser.nextText();
          }
          break;
        case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
          break;
        } // end switch

        eventType = parser.next();  
      } // end while
        return result;      
     }


} // end CallAPI
```

Now in your activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

// This is the method that is called when the submit button is clicked
public void verifyDetails(View view) {
    EditText schidEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sch_id);
    String schid = schidEditText.getText().toString();

    if( schid != null && !schid.isEmpty()) {
        String urlString = apiURL + "schid:" + schid.toString();
        //String urlString = apiURL + "LicenseInfo.RegisteredUser.UserID=" + strikeIronUserName + "&LicenseInfo.RegisteredUser.Password=" + strikeIronPassword + "&VerifyEmail.Email=" + email + "&VerifyEmail.Timeout=30";
      new CallAPI().execute(urlString); 
    }   




}



}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **DocumentBuilderFactory** for Parsing XML using Java

You can find a good tutorial for this on that place [XML and Java - Parsing XML using Java](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=152)

Answer (score 0):

Check [Xml Parsing Tuotorial using DOM parser](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/)

also [Xml Parsing Tuotorial using XML pull parser](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidXML/article.html)